# T-SQL concatenate string from rows

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

I try to update a column in a temporary table by concatenating rows from another table.

Look at this:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
     EmployeeId INT
     ,Html VARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE #EmployeeItems
(
    EmployeeId INT
    ,ItemNo INT
);

INSERT INTO #EmployeeItems (EmployeeId, ItemNo)
VALUES
    (1, 1)
    ,(1, 2);

INSERT INTO #Test (EmployeeId, Html) VALUES (1, '<div class="first">');
SET @Test = '<div class="first">';

UPDATE T SET Html += '<div class="second">' + CAST(E.ItemNo AS VARCHAR) + '</div>'
FROM #Test AS T
    JOIN #EmployeeItems AS E ON T.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId;

SELECT @Test += '<div class="second">' + CAST(E.ItemNo AS VARCHAR) + '</div>'
FROM #Test AS T
JOIN #EmployeeItems AS E ON T.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId;

UPDATE #Test SET Html += '</div>';
SET @Test += '</div>';

SELECT Html FROM #Test;
SELECT @Test;

DROP TABLE #Test;
DROP TABLE #EmployeeItems;
```

The column in the #Test table contains: `<div class="first"><div class="second">1</div></div>`

And the @Test variable contains: `<div class="first"><div class="second">1</div><div class="second">2</div></div>`

Why is this? What difference is it? I thought I would get the same results but in the table case it only concatenates one row, the first.

What should I do instead to update my table without running a cursor?

**EDIT**

My original problem comes from something like this:

My input data is

```
CREATE TABLE #Actions(EmployeeId INT,EmployeeName VARCHAR(100),ActionStart TIME,ActionEnd TIME,Type VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #Actions(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,ActionStart,ActionEnd, Type)
VALUES (1,'Bob','09:00','12:00', 'action'),(1,'Bob','14:30','16:00', 'action'),(1,'Bob','18:00','20:00', 'event'),(2,'Susan','10:00','12:00', 'action');
```

I want output like this

```
<div class="employee" employeeid="1" employeename="Bob">
    <div class="action" start="09:00" end="12:00" type="action"></div>
    <div class="action" start="14:30" end="16:00" type="action"></div>
    <div class="action" start="18:00" end="20:00" type="event"></div>
</div>
<div class="employee" employeeid="2" employeename="Susan">
    <div class="action" start="10:00" end="12:00" type="action"></div>
</div>
```

Like the first example this is a simplified example. But if I solve a case I can solve my problem. How would you do this with the FOR XML clause?

Comment: Although it is possible, don't generate html in TSQL. What you can do is query `FOR XML` and use an xsl to transform the result. (for example, shouldn't you html encode your data?)

Comment: All right. I edited my question a little bit could you give me a hint of what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the variable concatenation as a quirk; it's unsupported behavior that gets used a lot in code :)  If you want to keep using it, you could modify your UPDATE statement like so:

```
UPDATE t 
SET HTML = @Test
FROM #test t
```

An alternate method would be to use the FOR XML syntax to concatenate

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
      EmployeeId INT
    , Html VARCHAR(MAX)
    ) ;
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeItems
    (
      EmployeeId INT
    , ItemNo INT
    ) ;
INSERT  INTO #EmployeeItems
        ( EmployeeId, ItemNo )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 )     ,
        ( 1, 2 ) ;
INSERT  INTO #Test
        ( EmployeeId, Html )
VALUES  ( 1, '<div class="first">' ) ;

UPDATE  #Test
SET     HTML+= REPLACE(REPLACE(( SELECT '|div class="second"|'
                                        + CAST(E.ItemNo AS VARCHAR) + '|/div|'
                                 FROM   #Test AS T
                                        JOIN #EmployeeItems AS E ON T.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
                               FOR
                                 XML PATH('')
                               ), '|div class="second"|',
                               '<div class="second">'), '|/div|', '</div>')    
UPDATE  #Test
SET     Html += '</div>' ;

SELECT  Html
FROM    #Test ;


DROP TABLE #Test ;
DROP TABLE #EmployeeItems ;
```

Or (and perhaps best), just build your XML document directly.

```
SELECT  'first' AS "div/@class"
      , 'second' AS "div/div/@class"
      , e.ItemNo AS "div/div"
FROM    #EmployeeItems e
FOR     XML PATH('')
```

Additional Answer for edited question:

```
BEGIN TRAN


CREATE TABLE #Actions
    (
      EmployeeId INT
    , EmployeeName VARCHAR(100)
    , ActionStart TIME
    , ActionEnd TIME
    , Type VARCHAR(10)
    ) ;
INSERT  INTO #Actions
        ( EmployeeId, EmployeeName, ActionStart, ActionEnd, Type )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Bob', '09:00', '12:00', 'action' ),
        ( 1, 'Bob', '14:30', '16:00', 'action' ),
        ( 1, 'Bob', '18:00', '20:00', 'event' ),
        ( 2, 'Susan', '10:00', '12:00', 'action' ) ; 

;
WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        EmployeeID
                      , EmployeeName
               FROM     #actions
             )
    SELECT  'employee' AS "@class"
          , employeeid AS "@employeeid"
          , employeename AS "@employeename"
          , ( SELECT    'action' AS "@class"
                      , ActionStart AS "@start"
                      , ActionEnd AS "@end"
                      , Type AS "@type"
              FROM      #Actions a2
              WHERE     a2.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeID
            FOR
              XML PATH('div')
                , TYPE
            )
    FROM    cte a
FOR     XML PATH('div') 


ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: The second option actually answer my question, so here you go. But please look at my edited question, perhaps I overdo my solution. There may be an easier answer to my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the test table, the update is done for each row, so if you select all rows from the table you'll get two rows:

```
<div class="first"><div class="second">1</div></div>
<div class="first"><div class="second">2</div></div>
```

In the second case, it will add the `'<div class="second">' + CAST(E.ItemNo AS VARCHAR) + '</div>'` as many times as there are rows in the table. Since you got two rows, it'll add the two divs to the variable.

If you want each row of the table to have the value of `@Test` you don't need a cursor. Just update the table to have the value of `@Test`.